# How to use cv::imencode on IplImage?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an image saved in a variable fo type IplImage like this:

```
IplImage* fIplImageHeader;
fIplImageHeader = cvCreateImageHeader(cvSize(width, height), 8, 3);
fIplImageHeader->imageData = (char*) memblock;
```

How can I use the cv::imencode function on that image?

cv:imencode looks like this:

```
bool imencode(const string& ext, const Mat& img, vector<uchar>& buf, const vector<int>& params=vector<int>())
```

So obviously I need to convert IplImage to const Mat somehow but I cannot find how to do that in the documentation.

What should I do?

This does not work of course:

```
cv::imencode("JPG", fIplImageHeader, fIplImageHeader);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my other question:

[OpenCV - could not find encoder for the specified extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254460/opencv-could-not-find-encoder-for-the-specified-extension)

Where I have solved the problem.