# OpenCV - could not find encoder for the specified extension

Tags: c++, opencv

Here is my code I am using to convert *IplImage to jpg:

```
IplImage* fIplImageHeader;
fIplImageHeader = cvCreateImageHeader(cvSize(160, 120), 8, 3);
fIplImageHeader->imageData = (char*) memblock;

vector<int> p;
p.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY);
p.push_back(10);
vector<unsigned char> buf;
cv::imencode("JPEG", fIplImageHeader, buf, p);

cvReleaseImageHeader(&fIplImageHeader);
```

But I am getting this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (could not find encoder for the specified extension) in imencode, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.1.0/src/highgui/loadsave.cpp, line 409
```

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/buildd/opencv-2.1.0/src/highgui/loadsave.cpp:409: error: (-2) could not find encoder for the specified extension in function imencode

Why is that? I have OpenCV 2.1 installed. And this works so obviously jpg encoder must be there:

```
cvSaveImage("/home/richard/im.jpg", fIplImageHeader);
```

Comment: Have you tried `"jpeg"` and `"jpg"` instead of `"JPEG"`?  The documentation for imencode (http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html) doesn't explicitly list upper case extensions as supported.

Comment: @misha I tried "JPG", "JPEG", "jpg", "jpeg". The same error for all.

Comment: @misha - seems like ".jpg" works :)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Ok. I've figured this out. This works:

```
cv::imencode(".jpg", fIplImageHeader, buf, p);
```

They should mention it somewhere in the documentation that there should be a full stop before extension.

Comment: This is just :sadface:

Comment: 14 years later... `jpg_img = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)` where `img = cv2.imread("image.jpg")`  . Was missing the same full stop `.` in imencode